# When i click button the value is not sending in js?

Tags: javascript

I make mini app to find factorial. When i click button and get number in `js` it is not showing any thing.
This is my `script.js`

```
function factorial() {
let number = document.getElementById("number")
console.log(number);
for (let i = number - 1; i >= 1; i++) {
    number = i * number
    console.log(number);
}
console.log(number);
return number;
}
```

this is my `index.html`

```
<input type="text" name="number" class="number" id="number">
<button onclick="factorial()" class="btn btn-primary " style="padding-right: 160px;padding-left: 160px">Find</button>
```

Comment: where do you expect `return number;` to be returned to?

Comment: oh, I see `for (let i = number - 1; i >= 1; i++) {` ... number will ALWAYS be >= 1 if you add 1 every time (unless you enter 1)

Comment: i want to return this in html file

Comment: yes, but where do you think `return` will go? I'll put you out of your misery. Nowhere. Event handlers return value goes nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this for example:

```js
function factorial() {
  let number = document.getElementById("number").value
  console.log(number);
  for (let i = number - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
      number = i * number
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = number
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="number" class="number" id="number">
<button onclick="factorial()" class="btn btn-primary " style="padding-right: 160px;padding-left: 160px">Find</button>
<h3 id="result"></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called [.value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp). This will return the inner value of inputs (You can try it). After you achieved the value of the input, then you can run your statement.

> Read about **.textContent** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

> Read about **.querySelector()** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

**Tip**: Don't ever use *onclick()*. No one uses it anymore, use [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

```js
function factorial() {

// Edited here
let number = document.getElementById("number").value;
console.log(number);
for (let i = number - 1; i >= 1; i++) {
    number = i * number
    console.log(number);
}

  // As you wanted to put the result in the html file
  document.querySelector('h1').textContent += number;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="number" class="number" id="number">
<button onclick="factorial()" class="btn btn-primary " style="padding-right: 160px;padding-left: 160px">Find</button>

<h1>Result: </h1>
```